# Making HTTPConnection using Android SDK

Tags: android, httpclient

I need to make a connection to a url with parameters that is also using Basic authentication.  Per my google search, here's what I have:

```
String param = "?LS_ACCOUNT_SECRET=" + 
    URLEncoder.encode("dafsd","UTF-8") + 
    "&LS_ACCOUNT_SALT=" + URLEncoder.encode("dasfds","UTF-8");
url = new URL(com.jcs.toolbox.SitterMaticApi.API_REGISTER + param);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", 
    "Basic pass:word");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(
    urlConnection.getOutputStream());
wr.write(param);
wr.flush(); 

// Get the response
responseInputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    urlConnection.getInputStream())); 
String line; 
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
    acct +=  line;
}

//wr.close(); 
rd.close();
File acctfile = new File("maticacct.dat");
acctfile.createNewFile();
BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(acctfile,true));
buf.append(acct);
buf.newLine();
buf.close();
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("New Account").
    setMessage("New Account: " + acct).
    setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
```

I tried HTTPGet but I get "Get method not allowed":

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(sb.toString());
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content)); 
String line = null;
String acct = null;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
    acct +=  line;
}

rd.close();
content.close();
```

I have already added the permission for the app to use the internet. So any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post your stack trace.  Also, check to see if the internet permission is included in your manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did add the  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> tag in the manifest file.

Comment: The exception message that is displayed in the alert box: http://url/api?param=dfddf&param2=dasdfs.  It basically outputs the URL string that I am connecting to.

Comment: Is this an error that the server is returning, or an exception from your Java code?  You need to give as much detail about the error as possible, otherwise it will be difficult for someone to help you.

Comment: Maybe you should use POST method insted of GET?

Comment: Elevine - This is the exception from the phone app.

Comment: llya Zorin - I tried both POST and GET.  I did isolate the exact line that is giving me the exception.  The line: urlConnection.getInputStream() is the line that throws the exception.  I've commented one to test the other and both throws the exception.  thanks again for taking the time.  I'm sure I'm missing something very simple.